# javascript calling parent method from child

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I have the following object:

```
var party =
{
   food:
   {
       serve: function () {
         // I want to call turnOff method from here
       }

       cleanUp: function () {
       }
   }

   music:
   {
       turnOff: function () {
       }
   }
}
```

So as the comment points out, I want to call the turnOff method from the music object, how can I do this? `this` refers to the food object but I need to access the music object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var party =
{
   food:
   {
       serve: function () {
         party.music.turnOff();
       },
       cleanUp: function () {
       }
   },
   music:
   {
       turnOff: function () {
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is actually cleaner from the standpoint of maintainability... but the other response is equally valid if not a bit more protective of scope. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a constructor instead of a literal with a variable referencing the parent object

```
var party = new (function()
{
   var self = this;
   this.food =
   {
       serve: function () {
           self.music.turnoff();
       },

       cleanUp: function () {
       }
   }

   this.music = 
   {
       turnOff: function () {
       }
   }
})();
```

Comment: What are the advantages of doing this compared to simply calling `party.music.turnOff()`?

Comment: Is it that it won't have do a search for party in the global/whichever scope?

Comment: There aren't any. Except that you're no longer referencing by explicit name. Although, you do have a closure here which inhibits potential variable collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Call it as `party.music.turnOff`().

FYI, your above code block isn't valid.  You're missing some commas - after the `serve` and `food` closing braces.